# data fetch according to range as compare to user data in PHP

Tags: php

This is MY DB Table:

```
id      target_download     date
1       10                  2019-06-18
2       20                  2019-06-18
3       30                  2019-06-18
4       40                  2019-06-18
```

If suppose user **download = 15** it will count in **10 to 19 range** and get **first-row id = 1**

If suppose user **download = 25** it will count in **20 to 29 range** and get **second-row id = 2**

So get data according to user download and range.

I think you understand my question.

I Try This:

```
$=i;
foreach ($datas as $key=>$val){

    if($datas[$i]['targer_download'] >= $user_download && $datas[$i+1]['targer_download'] < $user_download){

    }
```

}

Comment: Did you've tried something? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Where is your code effort? Show us. We will be pleased to help you after that

Comment: I update my question with my tried Code.

Comment: @AbidHussain  show us the query code

Comment: I think you should define two fields one is min range and other is max range. So when you will hit the query you can check less than and greater than.

My questions regarding your query.
1. What is in $i?
2. Describe more what do you want to achieve with the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$data[]['target_download'] = 10;
$data[]['target_download'] = 20;
$data[]['target_download'] = 30;
$data[]['target_download'] = 40;
$user_download = 15;
foreach($data as $key => $val) {
   if($user_download >= $val['target_download'] && $user_download < $data[++$key]['target_download']) {      
    //Do your stuff
    echo "Range is ".$val['target_download'];
  }
}
```

I am assuming that you will be getting your data from DB with a numeric array.

**EDIT**
Other solution

```
    $arr = array(10, 20, 30, 40);
    function getClosest($search, $arr) {
       $a = null;
       foreach ($arr as $i) {
          $a = $search >= $i ? $i : $a;
       }
       return $a===null ? 0:$a;
    }

    echo $v = getClosest(15, $arr);
```